# Data analysis by R language. How to discribe the distribution of NA positon in a vector?

Tags: r

I hope the position distribution of NA is uniform in the vector (length = 30, NA < 6 ).

This one length is 30, 4 NA. It's easy to see these NA not uniform, mainly at left.

vector_x <- c(NA,3, NA, 1, NA, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 2, 12, 324, 54,23, 12, 324, 122, 23, 324, 332, 45, 78, 32, 12, 342, 95, 67, NA)

But I have no idea about use which kind of statistic or test to discribe. Then I can quantitative screening by a cutoff.

Now, I have two preliminary thoughts.
To simplify the solution, all NA seemed as 0 and all number seemed as 1, to see the distribution.
Or I get the index of NA, to do variance analysis about c(1, 3, 5, 30)

Thanks for your any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the index of `NA` elements, use `is.na` to convert to a `logical` vector, then with `which` returns the numeric index where it is TRUE

```
which(is.na(vector_x))
#[1]  1  3  5 30
```

Or to convert to a binary vector where 0 represents NA and 1 for other values

```
as.integer(!is.na(vector_x))
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to perform a [Mann-Whitney U test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) or Wilcoxon rank-sum test (which is more descriptive of what it's doing)

This is easy to do with your data

```
which(is.na(v))
# [1]  1  3  5 30

which(!is.na(v))
# [1]  2  4  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29

wilcox.test(which(is.na(v)), which(!is.na(v)))

        # Wilcoxon rank sum test

# data:  which(is.na(v)) and which(!is.na(v))
# W = 29, p-value = 0.1766
# alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Check that wilcox.test works the way we expect with

```
wilcox.test(1:5, 6:10)  # low p value
wilcox.test(seq(1,10,2), seq(2,10,2)) # high p value
```

Comment: Yes, I even never think of this way. But it looks like these two vectors lke two samples and from one population, and different length, so I'm not sure there are some  requirements to satisfy if use this test...Thanks